# Inheriting wx.grid.GridCellTextEditor

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I am trying to intercept the text being typed into the Cell Editor of a wx.grid object by creating a custom cell editor and setting it as the default cell editor of my grid.

As a test I did the following:

```
class CellEditor(wx.grid.GridCellTextEditor):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.MessageBox("Init")
        super(CellEditor, self).__init__()

    def BeginEdit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.MessageBox("Begin Edit")
        super(CellEditor, self).BeginEdit(*args, **kwargs)
```

While the "Init" message box shows up, the "begin edit" message box never appears.  Even if I explicitly call the `BeginEdit()` method from the debugger, the message box is not displayed.  This makes me think somehow the BeginEdit method is being re-written over by the original method during initialization.  Come someone help me understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not completely understand the magic behind the custom cell editors, but this [**example**](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/GridCustEditor.py) may be a good starting point. It seems that you have to override more methods in order to make it work.

Also I would be careful with overriding methods, your method signature `BeginEdit(self, *args, **kwargs)` does not match the overriden one which is `BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid)`. I did some quick tests to see if you can override methods like this and it seems so, but it is confusing and may lead to mistakes.